# Set open_basedir() for subdirectories as that subdirectory

Tags: php, .htaccess, open-basedir

I want to be able to set a `open_basedir()` in my `.htaccess` of /home, and say a user creates /home/username, I want the to be able to restrain that subdirectory /home/username to /home/username without creating any files inside of /home/username. Is there any way to do that?